# Changing the value of a single node in XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have the following XML document:

```
<People>
  <Person>
    <Name>Dylan</Name>
    <Email>email</Email>
    <Age>4</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Name</Name>
    <Email>name</Email>
    <Age>16</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>ok</Name>
    <Email>name</Email>
    <Age>16</Age>
  </Person>
</People>
```

This is the code used to create the file, hope that helps.
I'm trying to be able to select a certain Person via their name and change update their age to another value. I've managed to compare a user entered name with one in the document but have no idea how to go about updating the age after this.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Dylan\\Desktop\\people.xml");
string name = textBox1.Text;
bool correct = false;

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//Person"))
{
    string Name = node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
    if (Name == name)
    {
        //code to change age
    }
    if (correct == true) break;
 }
```

This is the code used to create the file:

```
     XmlTextWriter x = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Users\\Dylan\\Desktop\\people.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        x.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        x.WriteStartElement("People");
        x.WriteStartElement("Person");
        x.WriteStartElement("Name");
        x.WriteString(textBox1.Text);
        x.WriteEndElement();
        x.WriteStartElement("Email");
        x.WriteString(textBox2.Text);
        x.WriteEndElement();
        x.WriteStartElement("Age");
        x.WriteString(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
        x.WriteEndElement();
        x.WriteEndElement();
        x.WriteEndElement();
        x.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Created!");
```

Comment: Your XML snippet does not show the format of the XML. Could you include the actual XML you are using so we can know which values are elements and which attributes?

Comment: I've added the code I used to create the XML file in the question, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to update the age as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Dylan\\Desktop\\people.xml");
string name = textBox1.Text;
bool correct = false;

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//Person"))
{
    string Name = node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
    if (Name == name)
    {
        // Using the Person node, select the Age node
        XmlNode ageNode = node.SelectSingleNode("Age");

        // Update the value with whatever new value is required
        ageNode.InnerText = "10";
    }

    if (correct == true) break;
}

// Remember to save the changes!
doc.Save("C:\\Users\\Dylan\\Desktop\\people.xml");
```